# Problem while trying to implement iterative solution to fibonacci series using lists

Tags: python, list

```
 def fibo(m):
  dp = []
  for i in range(m+1):
    dp.append(0)
  dp[0] = 1
  dp[1] = 1
  if(m>1):
    for i in range(2,m+1):
      dp[i] = dp[i-1] + dp[i -1]
  return dp[m]
```

I am getting an error that says that the list index is out of bound can any resolve it and can post the correct code . Thanks.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-ea67e751dd0e> in <module>()
     12   return dp[m]
     13 
---> 14 fibo(0)

<ipython-input-92-ea67e751dd0e> in fibo(m)
      6     dp.append(0)
      7   dp[0] = 1
----> 8   dp[1] = 1
      9   if(m>1):
     10     for i in range(2,m+1):

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: Your code shows `range(m+1)`, but the traceback `range(m)`.

Comment: `range(0+1)` is just `0`. So you don't create `dp[1]` when you call `fibo(0)`

Answer (score 1):

When `m == 0`, the initial `for` loop only appends `dp[0]`, so assigning to `dp[1]` gets an error.

Instead of assigning after the loop, append `1` in the loop. The elements after `dp[1]` will then be overwritten by the second loop, so it doesn't matter what their original values are.

```
def fibo(m):
    dp = []
    for i in range(m+1):
        dp.append(1)
    if(m>1):
        for i in range(2,m+1):
            dp[i] = dp[i-1] + dp[i-2]
    return dp[m]
```

Another way to do it is to initialize `dp` with the first two elements, and then append to it in the loop that calculates each element of the series.

```
def fibo(m):
    dp = [1, 1]
    if(m>1):
        for i in range(2,m+1):
            dp.append(dp[i-1] + dp[i-2])
    return dp[m]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why adding zeros to your list before assigning values ? When you pass `m = 0`, you will have an error when trying to access `dp[1]`.

Also, there is a typo in `dp[i] = dp[i-1] + dp[i -1]`. Fibonacci is the sum of the `(n-1)`th and `(n-2)`th elements like this `dp[i] = dp[i-1] + dp[i -2]`

I would do something like :

```
def fibo(m):
  dp = []
  dp.append(0)
  dp.append(1)
  if(m>1):
    for i in range(2,m+1):
      dp.append(dp[i-1] + dp[i -2])
  return dp[m]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also initialize the `dp` list in the beginning to the length of the number and then just store the answer in the respective index.

```
def fib(n):
    if n<=1:
        return n
    dp=[0]*(n+1)
    dp[1]=1
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        dp[i]=dp[i-2]+dp[i-1]
    return dp[n]

>>> print(fib(5))
5
>>> print(fib(9))
34
```

Answer (score 0):

The IndexError you are seeing occurs when you pass in m as 0. In this case the list contains just a single element( dp = `[0]` ), but your code tries to access the second element by index:
i.e. `dp[1] = 1`  (hence the index error)

An easy way to get around this is to not initialize the list at all, and directly start appending your fibonacci series numbers to it.

```
def fibo(m):
   dp = []
   dp.append(1)
   dp.append(1)
   # Use a loop for the remainder of the numbers. Will only execute if m > 1
   for i in range(2,m+1):
       dp.append(dp[i-1] + dp[i-2])
   return dp[m]
```

An alternative solution would be to not use a list at all (since you are only interested in the nth element of the series). The solution is quite concise:

```
def fibo(m):
    a, b = 1, 1
    while (m > 0):
         a, b = b, a+b   # At every iteration, "a" takes the value of the next element in the fibo series.
         m -= 1
    return a
```